# Woocommerce: orders invisible on My Account page

Tags: woocommerce

I recently migrated a site to new hosting, and apparently orders from before the migration don't show up on the 'My Account' page anymore. New orders do show up.

Does anyone know of a way to remedy this?

The website URL: [www.toscanzahoeve.be](http://www.toscanzahoeve.be)

Thank you,
Stefaan

Comment: Were you using the same version of WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you migrated you probably didn't manually export and import the databse, you must have used some other form of import/export. If that's true, go to PHPMyAdmin and manually export the database, then manually insert it in PHPMyAdmin at your new host. Make sure to use custom settings and select zipped as the output format of he export. Not doing so sometimes causes errors with the import after that. Keep backups of everything!

Comment: Indeed, I used the Duplicator plugin for this. Do you mean the entire Wordpress database?

The website is now live since a more than a week, so export/import of the old database is no longer an option, I fear... So there's nothing I can do about this?

Comment: I think at this point your best option is to go to the orders management page and then edit each order one by one. In the order edit screen there's a drop down named "Customer:" From that you can search for and pick the right customer - if they were all imported. Let me know if this helps!